# min-width on inline (not inline-block) behaving element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to set the min-width on a contenteditable div with some other elements next to it that must stay inline with the div.

Every solution I've seen uses inline-block, but I can't use inline-block behavior. When inline-block starts wrapping, it still behaves like a block element, and I need the div to behave as an inline element. I would imagine the solution would require more than just CSS, but it seems very difficult to set any event for when the div's text changes. A solution involving javascript and/or jQuery would be welcome.

EDIT: Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to do. If the user would type more text than the page is wide, there is a difference in behavior between inline-block and block, and that's what I am concerned with.

```
<style type="text/css">
label {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
#container {
    font-size: 32px;
}
#content {
    display: inline;
    min-height: 37px; /* doesn't work on inline elements */
    min-width: 80px; /* also doesn't work on inline elements */
}
</style>

<div id="container">
    <input type="radio" />
    <label>
        <span></span>
    </label>
    <span>(A)</span>
    <div id="content" contenteditable="true" unselectable="off">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: please post some of your markup over here what you've tried so far

Comment: We need some code to work with... Maybe make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: You should probably just throw input, label, and span into a container, give that a specific width + float left, then do what you want with the rest of the space. Seems like you're trying to solve something by approaching it backwards. Inline can't have dimensions. You can always add a fixed width onto #container if you want absolutely no wrapping at that point. Just my two cents. Not an official answer

Comment: @mr.stobbe I can't quite do that, because the entire reason I need a fixed width contenteditable div is so the user can click on it when it's empty and add text. It's fine, I think at this point I'm going to use a really hackity javascript solution where I listen for all events ever on the div, then change the width based on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, here's the answer I came up with (in jQuery). Can anyone give me suggestions on leaving out some of these events that might not change the div's content or place a border around the div? (I'm also concerned with cut/paste).

```
$('#content').bind('blur focus load resize scroll click dblclick ' +
        'mousedown mouseup mousemove change ' +
        'select keydown keypress keyup', function () {
    if($(this).width() <= 80) {
        $(this).css("display", "inline-block");
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("display", "inline");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Now used to `floating`

as like this

```
a{
background:green;
  min-height:200px;
  float:left;
}
```

live demo http://tinkerbin.com/3Ho3Af9c

Comment: @V413HAV It works though, so would more than likely work as a content editable flagged container (rendering is still basically the same).

Comment: This is not the requested behavior. The link is a block element because `float: left;` is specified.

Comment: @Arjan You're right. It's effectively an inline-block. But I think this problem isn't actually solvable if the OP's looking for a magic bullet. They want to set minimum dimensions on something that's fluid. That's exactly what this trick or inline-block does. The float solves the other problem. inline means fluid. block means dimensions. It's as simple as that. Imagine if you set a minimum height on an inline element that wrapped partially. What would that look like? It's a block.