# Create paragraph with placeholders

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to create paragraph of text with missing words as on the picture provided:

[image]

I want user to fill missing words, and thus I'd like to make `spans` (that are placeholders for missing words) `contentEditable=true`

Is it possible to achieve with css?

Comment: the width of your span should be fixed?

Comment: Do you want the user to be able to type the missing words directly into the blanks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a `border-bottom` to your span (and `display: inline-block`): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLERdp

```
span[contenteditable] {
  border-bottom: 1px #333 solid;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 1.3em // firefox bug
  display: inline-block;
}
```

You could even add some style to highlight empty `span` and warn the user, e.g.

```
[contenteditable]:empty {
   background: yellow;
}
```

---

Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Fabrizio Calderan for your excellent answer. I have two issues though. 1. When I click a placeholder, my cursor appears under the line. 2. I would like my placeholder span to wrap like a regular span when user types two or more sentences. Is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: you're welcome. 1.Could you show the issue? I can't see it in my example 2. Just continue typing words with all the needed spaces, the span will adapt its width.

Comment: I noticed that the first problem occurs only in firefox (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25150739/pl.png). I assume that it is bug of firefox (not of your code). Second, I'd like my placeholder to behave as inline element (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25150739/wrap-desired.png), now it behaves as block element (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25150739/wrap-current.png). I can achieve it with by setting `display: inline;`, but I have no idea how to set minimum width for placeholder then.

Comment: for the behaviour of the element a question was already asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572905/min-width-on-inline-not-inline-block-behaving-element - Basically you need to switch from inline-block to inline via javascript, when the element width is greater than a min-width @AlexSmolov

Comment: Thank you very much!! It is very helpful!

Answer (score 5):

HTML:

```
This is text <input type="text" class="a" /> and here is a space.
```

CSS:

```
.a{
    border:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width:50px;
}
```

Comment: If @Alex wants his user to fill in the missing words, then this is the proper way to do that, instead on using `<span>` tags.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible

```
id-of-span{ 
   width:40px;
   height: 1px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
```

Answer (score 2):

Like described on the fairly popular tutorial [Natural Language Form with Custom Input Elements](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/21/natural-language-form-with-custom-input-elements/), it's also possible to achieve this with a few inputs and `Javascript`, which will be switched into span and div.

This way is actually very useful if you want to send the data as it's build as a form at the beginning.

Good Luck'

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course you can simply give those spans the style you need:

Use a `border-bottom` to specify that this span should be edited, to give the placeholder effects:

```css
span.missingWords {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  min-width: 50px;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
Any <span class='missingWords' contenteditable="true"> </span> with the contenteditable attribute set will have a grey outline <span class='missingWords'></span>as you hover over. Feel free to edit <span class='missingWords' contenteditable="true"> </span> and
change their contents. I'm using <span class='missingWords' contenteditable="true"> </span>local storage to maintain your changes.
```

**EDIT:**

And to make it look like a normal text after editing you can apply this javascript function on it:

```
$('.missingWords').bind('keyup', function() {
    $(this).css('border-bottom', 'none');
});
```